# ASCII check mark character causes imperfect box

Tags: html, css

It seems the ASCII character `&#x2713;` (check mark) is causing issues. You can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/2d3dqtdz/ the second box is a bit smaller.

Now consider changing the `&#x2713;` character with something like `&#8226;` ( a dot) and you can see the box is perfect.

How can I make the box look perfect when using the checkmark ASCII character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would to be assign a `line-height` to the element.

```css
.box {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  &#x2713; test
  <br />&#x2713; test
  <br />
</div>

<div class="box">
  &#x2713; test
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div class="box">
  &#8226; test
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```